# How do I make my custom wordpress theme consistent across all the pages?

Tags: wordpress

How do I make my custom wordpress theme consistent across all the pages? The homepage is looking okay but when I go to other page the header and layout is not like the homepage already.

Screenshots.
Main page

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RaPFW.jpg

When I go to other page

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Kog1.jpg

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. You might consider sharing some more information on your quesion. Screenshots or partial codes would help most of the time. Maybe for this example a link to the actual website would be nice.

Comment: I added the screenshots of it. You can have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Documentation is your friend: http://codex.wordpress.org/Main_Page.
Se section `Learn How to Use WordPress`and `Working With Themes` :)

You have to understand that the start page usually always has one template. As do a page and a post.

When you open a page, `page.php` is fired, and when you open a post, `post.php` is fired. They might both have different layout.

Comment: Hmm, I'm actually using Wordpress for business website purpose. I don't need comments and post feature, but I do need the pages function.

Comment: Then open the tempalte and remove the comment code. You can also enable comments from wp-admin. If you don't like the default template, you can always find and download free templates. You can find some here: http://www.simplewpthemes.com/ - or just google `free wordpress themes`

Comment: I tried to remove the comment feature via wp-admin settings, but whenever I go to other page example about us page, the comment box will still appear. The header and the layout is not in their appropriated order also.

Comment: Yes, because even if you turn this off, the theme might still show the HTML for comments. So you have to open the file and remove the code - or find another theme that does not have the comment code.

Comment: May I know the location of the files? I'm still new to Wordpress.

Comment: You have to read the documentation: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy. It also helps if you have some PHP programming skills. Or, as I've said earlier, download and install a new theme that does not use comments. Good luck. PS. If you have found this answer usefull, click the up arrow to award points + tick the 'V' for closing this questions. PPS. Do not change the text in the original question. Keep it and rater add notes / updates.